# how to add a new attribute in Video tag using jquery .prepend()?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to add the attribute `controls` inside the tag videos using js .prepend()
My code is:

```
item.prepend($('<video/>',  {src: file[options.baseUrlAttribute] + '' +file[options.pathAttribute]} ));
```

and the generated HTML is:

```
<video src="/mysite/media/videos/videofile.mp4"></video>
```

What i need is to add the attribute `controls=""` inside the `<video>` tag

so the generated HTML become:

```
<video src="/mysite/media/videos/videofile.mp4" controls=""></video>
```

I tried this code:

```
item.prepend($('<video controls=""/>',  {src: file[options.baseUrlAttribute] + '' +file[options.pathAttribute]} ));
```

but didn't work and now the generated HTML is:

```
<video controls=""></video>
```

What i am doing wrong and how i can edit this specific code to make it work?

```
item.prepend($('<video/>',  {src: file[options.baseUrlAttribute] + '' +file[options.pathAttribute]} ));
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery? What's `item`?

Comment: Yes and i must edit the question, Thanks for the mention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK after some more tries the following code worked great for me:

```
item.prepend($('<video/>',  {controls:"", src: file[options.baseUrlAttribute] + '' +file[options.pathAttribute]} ));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can pass parameters inside prepend, this can address cross-scripting injections, as described at the [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/prepend/):

> By design, any jQuery constructor or method that accepts an HTML string — jQuery(), .append(), .after(), etc. — can potentially execute code. This can occur by injection of script tags or use of HTML attributes that execute code (for example, ). Do not use these methods to insert strings obtained from untrusted sources such as URL query parameters, cookies, or form inputs. Doing so can introduce cross-site-scripting (XSS) vulnerabilities. Remove or escape any user input before adding content to the document.

```js
const mySource = 'http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4'

const video = document.querySelector('video')

// width pure JavaScript
// video.src = mySource


// with jQuery
$('video').attr('src', 'http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4');
```

```css
video {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 260px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video autoplay="true"></video>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I need just a suggest for editing my existing code.

Comment: No worries, I edited the answer. I don't think you can do it in the way you're trying to do due to a security issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
let videoElement = document.createElement('VIDEO');
let videoSrc = file[options.baseUrlAttribute] + '' +file[options.pathAttribute];
videoElement.src = videoScr
videoElement.controls = ""
item.prepend(videoElement)
```